# Why does mono sometimes truncate http downloads?

Tags: c#, mono

I use the following code to download text (json):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    string charset = null;
    var httpResponse = response as HttpWebResponse;
    if (httpResponse != null)
    {
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new System.Net.WebException("Ststus code was: " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }
        charset = httpResponse.CharacterSet;
     }
     Encoding enc = charset != null ? Encoding.GetEncoding(charset) : null;
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc, true))
     {
         return reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

On Windows (.net) it works fine. On Linux (Mono runtime) it sometimes returns truncated data: The json parser crashes, because can't find the closing delimiter for strings and similar errors. It is not a problem with the parser: I have tried 2 different. It does not seem to be a problem with encoding, because it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't for the exact same downloaded data.

Why would mono behave this way and how can I avoid this problem?

Edit: I added a console print for debugging purposes. The string coming directly from the code above is definitively truncated.

Edit2: Here is how I use the result:

```
string json = DownloadTextFile(url);
dynamic obj = Json.Decode(json);//Decoding fails here, because string is truncated.
```

Comment: I don't know much about Linux but I would start with a network trace of the HTTP traffic to verify that all data is being transmitted from the server to the client. That would rule out a low-level network issue on the Linux box.

Comment: Is the content-length wrong?

Comment: Try to catch it in the act: Add an assert to make sure that whatever the StreamReader returnes ends with a "}" so that you know it was valid JSON that went into the parser. I kind of bet that the platform is correct and the bug is yours...

Comment: @christoph: 1. The linux and windows machine are the same pc. 2. If a network problem occurs, i expect the framework methods to throw an ecxeption of some kind, instead of failing silently.

Comment: @usr If the problem is in my code, then tell me where it is. I posted all of the relevant parts above. Only thing that might be relevant other than that is that i use that function from multiple threads. But it does not use static or shared data, so it should be fine.

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: Mono version: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)

Comment: In case the problem is with the StreamReader, if it thinks the transmission is over before it actually is, could you try reading the stream directly using a buffer and a loop? The response should tell you how many payload bytes are being returned by the HTTP response. Instead of relying on whether there are any bytes left in the stream, the reading loop could use that number to wait for all data to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs much less frequently when I let the program run on a server with a good very good connection to the net. (After a few thousand downloads, instead of after a few hundred). That is good enough for my purposes.

Checking the content length does not help much, because it is -1 more often than not. It is sad that network stuff is implemented so poorly in mono. (On .net the same code works flawlessly even with a bad connection.)